# Mysql Down On Amazon EC2 Error Connecting To Database

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Our database shutdown last night and i cannot figure out why i just did a service restart to get everything backup, we are running a c4.large so quite a big box outputting the mysql error log is below.

```
160526 23:27:31 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160526 23:27:31 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160526 23:27:31 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160526 23:27:31 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
160526 23:27:31 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160526 23:27:31 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
160526 23:27:31 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160526 23:27:31 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
160526 23:27:31 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
160526 23:27:31 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
160526 23:27:31 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
160526 23:27:31 [ERROR] Aborting

160526 23:27:31 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Can someone help me with this error i see the fatal error cannot allocate memory for buffer pool but not sure what this means or how to fix?

Also what may have caused this?

Thanks

After googling a bit i have added

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 20M
```

to my.cnf is this a solid fix?

Comment: That's going to make your performance worse, even if it works.  Look at what else is running to figure out why you have so little free memory on the machine, and address that.

Comment: You have run out of RAM. You can allocate swap space. Set innodb_buffer_pool_size to 50% of available RAM.